# Jquery elements that pull from a database and send form to email

Tags: jquery, database, forms, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

OK. I will try to be as clear as possible and give my source code to try an help with what I am asking.

So I have these draggable elements which are pulled via a database that drag from one area to a droppable/sortable area. They are meant to be collected there so that the values they can be later submitted (emailed to me and the user). I'm trying to figure out how exactly how the code should be written in the forms so that way I am sure it will be picked up after it has been sorted the droppable area to send to an email.

here's my code for reference (the send form aspect has not been implemented in anyway just a placeholder right now): 
**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Matuduke/Y86As/

```
<style>

    .tooltip { position:fixed; top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3; display: none;}

    #send {float:left; position:relative; }
    #column_en { float:inherit;}
    #webwall { float:left; width:48%; padding: 3px; max-height:340px; min-height:340px; }
    #collectborder { float:left; width:50%; min-height:340px; padding: 0px; }


    #staticwall li {cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default !important; list-style-type: none; margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 84px; height: 144px; font-size:x-small; text-align: center; }

    #collection { list-style-type:none; min-height:340px; float:left; min-width:500px; border:dashed;background:#fff; height:30%; padding: .5% ; } * html #collecton { height: 0em; }
    #collection li { list-style-type:none; margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 84px; height: 144px; font-size: 1em; text-align: center;}


    </style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var removeIntent = false;
    $( "#collection").sortable({
     over: function () {
            removeIntent = false;
        },
        out: function () {
            removeIntent = true;
        },
        beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
            if(removeIntent == true){
                ui.item.remove();
                    }
                 }
        });
        $( "#collection").disableSelection();
            });

        $(document).ready(function() {
        var source;
        var destination;
        var fn = function(event, ui) {
            toDrop = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            if ($("#collection").find("li[uIdentity=" + toDrop.attr("uIdentity") + "]").length >= 0) {
                $("#collection").prepend(toDrop);
            }
            else
                return false;
        };
        $("#staticwall li, #collection li").draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
            hoverClass: "ui-state-default"
        });

        $("#collection").droppable({
            accept: "#staticwall li" ,
            drop: fn 
                    });
                });
            $("#staticwall li").setPos('0,0');
            $('#staticwall').tinyscrollbar();
        $(function() {

        $("#collection li").draggable({
            revert: true
                    });
                    });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>       
        <div id="column_en">
        <div id="webwall">
           Choose the pieces to add to your collection:
    <ul style="overflow:auto;height:300px;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;" id="staticwall" class="ui-state-default">

        <?php 
        mysql_connect('localhost','user,'pass');
        mysql_select_db("houstop9_Spiritiles");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT thumb, title, quote, sku FROM spiritiles ORDER BY `spiritiles`.`sku` DESC LIMIT 0, 120");

        // print the list items
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<li uIdentity='1' class='ui-state-default'>{$row['thumb']}\n {$row['sku']}</li>";

                }
                ?>

        </ul>
            </div>


        <div>Create your Collection here: </div>
        <div  id="collectborder" >
        <ul id="collection" class="ui-state-default">
            </ul>
            <div id="send"><form>
            <input type="text" accept="">
            <input type="image" accept="">

                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send Tiles'></form> 
            </div> 

            </div>
            </div>

            </body>
```

**EDIT:**
ok i think i get what you're saying but I'm not certain I understand the get method in JQuery. I've been trying make it run when i submit the form, but i think I'm fudging it all up:

```
     function getSku() 
        var myIds = new array();
        $("#collection li").each(function(index, element){
           getSelection(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
           myIds.push(element.id);

            });
         }
         $("form").submit(getSku);
```

Comment: Don't really understand what are you trying to do. I added a jsfiddle to your post.

Comment: Well ok, sorry for being unclear. And thx for adding the jsfiddle. That dashed box where you "Create your collection", I want everything a user drops into that box to be able to be submitted to me via an email. Not the objects themselves but the names of each object that is put in it. The problem is I can't quite figure out how to do this. Especially since each objects name and image are pulled from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you can iterate with `.each()` the elements of your dashed box, something like this:

```
var myIds = new array();
$("#collection li").each(function(index, element){
  // get ids
  myIds.push(element.id);
});
```

Then you have to make an array with the ids of your objects, and submit them. With PHP then you can send those ids via e-mail.

**EDIT**
In PHP when you create the `li` elements you have to do:

```
echo "<li uIdentity='1' class='ui-state-default' id='{$row['sku']}'>";
echo "  {$row['thumb']}\n {$row['sku']}";
echo "</li>";
```

I asume the `sku` is the primary key of your table. If not, the `id` property should reflect your primary key

Comment: hmmm... is it possible that these "Ids" can be a value in a database like a "sku number" or is it something that I have to handle inside the document in jquery? I mean I have about 100 different elements that are being pulled from a database to make the "#staticwall li" and the actual values in the database will change regularly. And I really need to make sure the Ids reflect the specific entry from the database.

Comment: I'm sorry if Im being confusing or not comprehending properly, and by "sku number" I meant like $row{['sku']} from a database. I think i need to look more into this .get() method...

Comment: Check my solution again (edit part). if `sku` is your primary key, you should put it on the `id` property of each `li` element. So, when you iterate the `li` elements, you can retrieve your ids.

Comment: ok can you help me out with this .get() thing for Jquery? I'm trying to get the function to run when the submit button is clicked to get the id's but well, I think I'm just being incompetent. could you check my edit?